# Logging user action in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, system

I'm working with a big project that a lot people participate in. We use a same MySQL database for development. The question is how can I know who have *done something* (insert, update, delete, run query, etc...) on database, when have they done it and what have they done. Assuming that everyone have a different account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use general logging.

It would log the details of the clients connect, disconnect and the queries run on the database.

To turn it on, set the following property in my.cnf:

```
general_log_file = /path/to/query.log
general_log      = 1
```

Or, you can set it from the console:

```
SET global general_log = 1;
```

Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to run through all your functions or procedures and adapt them to insert/update a "last editor" identifier, and add a field for that identifier to your tables. No easy way around that.

Comment: What if someone execute a pure query like update some rows in a table. Can i know who have ran that query? and What was that query?
What i want to do here is log every action of user when they working with database.

Comment: pretty thorough examination of this here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112128/how-to-know-which-user-update-insert-or-delete-in-mysql-database